# How to pass object values of an array in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React application, certain records are fetched from JSON and displayed in a grid. It also has text box and date fields when changed displays data accordingly on the table, but, I want to save all the data populated in the grid which doesn't happens as expected. I can see it in the console.
Please refer to code below.

```
 // Function for saving
  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log("DATA HERE", dataNew);
  };

  // Function for on change of text and date
  console.log("data new", dataNew);
  const handleChange = (data) => {
    const { id: newId, textVal: franchise, dateVal: dateData } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      const newList = [...prevInfo];
      const index = newList.findIndex((datum) => datum.newId === newId);

      // Here newData is mapped which I get from JSON data through props
      newData?.map((data) => {
        if (index !== -1) {
          if (newId !== undefined) {
            newList[index].newId = newId;
          }
          if (franchise !== undefined) {
            [...data, (newList[index].franchise = franchise)];
          }
          if (dateData !== undefined) {
            [...data, (newList[index].dateData = dateData)];
          }
        } else {
          [...data, newList.push({ newId, franchise, dateData })];
        }
      });

      return [...newList];
    });
  };
```

As seen from above code, I'am mapping all records of the table into the grid and want to save it in the function. The data saved in the function is only the changed values, but, all records aren't getting populated into that array. Just observe the console in the below image.

[image]

When clicking on Save function, it doesn't display records as expected. I mean all the records shown in the grid should be displayed with the changed values. What could be the best solution to tackle this issue?

Please refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-aryabhata-95o2sy?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: You are using `map` as a `forEach` here, and in so doing are mutating your state.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How can we tackle this? If possible can you please update the sandbox?

Comment: Your `gridData.data` is of a strange format being an array with column values in order, but an object containing the id: `[{id: 6705}, "McDonalds", "Burger Store", "Mike John", Sun Oct 10 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), "Best Food Chain"]`. Secondly, you pass the same handler to both the date and name inputs, but the passed argument doesn't indicate which is triggering the event. I would try to simplify down to a single state of a meaningful shape rather than trying to build/mirror the table data in parallel.

Comment: This simplest way to do this would be to manage `newCompData` in the NewComp component, rather than abstracting it and then rebuilding it in the `Table` component.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I could see was the way in which you were using the spread operator.
For example: this line of code

```
if (franchise !== undefined) {
   [...data, (newList[index].franchise = franchise)];
}
```

is concatenating a clone of data and the newList array (with a modified franchise value). Two issues here:

1. You are not just modifying the franchise but concatenating newList to data. As you are doing a similar thing for the dateData you are effectively adding newList to data multiple times.
2. You are not doing anything with the result from the spread operator.

Not sure if the changes I have made suit your exact requirements but the change does result in your dataNew state capturing updates to the grid.

```
const handleChange = (data) => {

    const { id: newId, textVal: franchise, dateVal: dateData } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      
      const index = prevInfo.findIndex((datum) => datum.newId === newId);
      
      if (index === -1) {
        return [...prevInfo, { newId, franchise, dateData }];
      } else {
        const newList = [...prevInfo];
        newList[index] = { newId, franchise, dateData };
        return newList;
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work as you aren't concatenating other values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need `dataNew` to begin with, why not just log the grid data?

```js
  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log("DATA HERE", gridData);
  };
```